# Stretch 4 bootstrap buttons on all row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnSave" onclick=" GetSaveData(); ">Save</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnSubmit" onclick=" GetSubmitData(); ">Submit</a>
        <asp:LinkButton class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnAttach" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnAttach_OnClick" Text="Attach" ></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnExit" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnExit_OnClick" Text="Exit"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have 4 buttons in row. How can i stretch this buttons on all row?
Currently it looks like : [image]

What i want looks like this : 
[image]

Comment: Use class="col-md-3" for each button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a div around each of them and give it the dimensions you want. Tried it on my website just now and I have four buttons stretching across the page.

```
  <div class="row">   
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnSave" onclick=" GetSaveData(); ">Save</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnSubmit" onclick=" GetSubmitData(); ">Submit</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
         <asp:LinkButton class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnAttach" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnAttach_OnClick" Text="Attach" ></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
        <asp:LinkButton class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnExit" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnExit_OnClick" Text="Exit"></asp:LinkButton>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: perhaps using `text-center` as well after `col-xs-6` will improve the result.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each button in a `.col-xs-3` div and apply a `text-align:center` on those divs:

```css
.row > div {
  text-align:center
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnSave" onclick=" GetSaveData(); ">Save</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnSubmit" onclick=" GetSubmitData(); ">Submit</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnAttach" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnAttach_OnClick" Text="Attach" >Attach</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <a class="btn btn-default" id="lnkBtnExit" runat="server" OnClick="lnkBtnExit_OnClick" Text="Exit">Exit</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```